# iOS app crashes on resuming

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash

**(SEE UPDATE AT THE BOTTOM)**

Recently I've started getting a weird and rare crash of my iPhone app when it returns from background. The crash log consists of system calls only:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000138
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34c715b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x368b7034 _CFXNotificationPost + 1424
2   Foundation                      0x34379d8c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
3   UIKit                           0x37ddfec2 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 1290
4   UIKit                           0x37c37d5c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1288
5   UIKit                           0x37c376d0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
6   UIKit                           0x37c3711e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
7   GraphicsServices                0x36dea5a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3693b680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3693aee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
10  CoreFoundation                  0x36939cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
11  CoreFoundation                  0x368aceb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
12  CoreFoundation                  0x368acd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
13  GraphicsServices                0x36de92e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
14  UIKit                           0x37c8b2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
15  [MyAppName]                     0x00083d60 main (main.m:20)
16  [MyAppName]                     0x00080304 start + 36
```

This might look like a zombie object being called on `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` or `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` (guessing by `_handleApplicationResumeEvent` in stack trace and the time when it crashes), but:

1. None of my classes register for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, and only a couple of singletons (that stay alive forever) register for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`;
2. I've done some experimenting, and it turns out that posting `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` goes from `[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks:]`, and it isn't in the crash log.

For me, all this implies a bug in some library I'm using, or a system bug, and the crash occurred once on iOS 5.1.1 (release build), once on iOS 6.0 (release build) and once on iOS 6.0 (debug build). I scanned every library I'm using and have access to the source code for, and they aren't registering for neither `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` nor `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. The only library I don't have access to is TestFlight, but the crash occurred on both 1.0 and 1.1 versions of TestFlight, and I've been using the former for quite a while now, without such problems.
So, summing up, I have no idea why has this crash come up and what's it coming from. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

I've investigated the issue a bit deeper, thanks to DarthMike and matt for their help. By using notification center callback and logging stack trace, I've discovered that this exact stack comes up when and only when `UIApplicationResumedNotification` notification is fired as a part of returning from background. And guess what - it's some "private" notification and it doesn't have a public identifier counterpart. It doesn't have `userInfo` and its object is `UIApplication` (as many other notifications that are posted before this). Obviously I don't use it, neither does any library I have source code for. I can't even find any reasonable mentioning of it in the Internet! I also highly doubt that TestFlight is the culprit, because crash happened during debug too, and I don't "take off" TestFlight in debug mode.

Here's the stack trace for receiving `UIApplicationResumedNotification`. The offsets are all the same but with a constant byte offset (2 or 4, depending on the library - probably because it's a debug stack tracing, not release):

```
0   [MyAppName]                         0x0016f509 NotificationsCallback + 72
1   CoreFoundation                      0x3598ce25 __CFNotificationCenterAddObserver_block_invoke_0 + 124
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35911037 _CFXNotificationPost + 1426
3   Foundation                          0x333d3d91 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
4   UIKit                               0x36e39ec7 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 1294
5   UIKit                               0x36c91d61 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1292
6   UIKit                               0x36c916d5 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
7   UIKit                               0x36c91123 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
8   GraphicsServices                    0x35e445a3 _PurpleEventCallback + 590
9   CoreFoundation                      0x35995683 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
10  CoreFoundation                      0x35994ee9 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
11  CoreFoundation                      0x35993cb7 __CFRunLoopRun + 646
12  CoreFoundation                      0x35906ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
13  CoreFoundation                      0x35906d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
14  GraphicsServices                    0x35e432eb GSEventRunModal + 74
15  UIKit                               0x36ce5301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
16  [MyAppName]                         0x000aa603 main + 390
17  [MyAppName]                         0x000a41b0 start + 40
```

NotificationsCallback is an "observer" callback I've added for debug just for now.

Just to prove a point, I've deliberately omitted a `removeObserver:` call from one of my objects to generate a zombie/exception, and stack trace still included `_CFXNotificationPost + 1426` followed by a crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `objc_msgSend + 16`, just as in my original crash.
So this just means that someone has registered an observer for `UIApplicationResumedNotification` and haven't removed it before the observer was deallocated. Based on the fact that I never registered for such a notification, I can assume that this crash is not my fault. Still the question remains - whose it is then? I wonder who actually registers for this notification anyway...

**UPDATE 2**

While I'm still waiting to see if there are any changes with this bug on the new version of my app, I've got another crash on the previous version caused by this. Turns out that whatever registers for `UIApplicationResumedNotification`, specifies selector `_applicationResuming:` for it. I doubt that's of any use though.

Comment: "For me, all this implies a bug in some library I'm using, or a system bug." I'm going to give you the best Cocoa touch programming advice you will ever get. Assume it's *you*.

Comment: If you are using Localytics, then this is a known issue for their library and they have dispatched an emergency update for their library

Comment: Thanks, Leftertis, but I don't use Localytics, I use TestFlight.

Comment: I generally would proceed as this for this kind of error: Remove parts of application till crash doesn't happen. Is it possible/easy for you to remove TestFlight usage, or remove other libs you are using, or even remove addObserver calls in your code? Removing that 1 by one should reveal problem. If it is framework problem then without ANY of you objects registering for ANY notification, crash should happen.

Comment: DarthMike, I don't think it's possible. There's a ton of code and a couple of libraries, and I receive crashes via TestFlight, so I need it. This crash happens **very** rarely, so - even if I don't see it anymore, it doesn't mean it's not there... I guess for the time being, I will just ignore it and wait if it happens again.

Comment: I understand you never register in your code for the crashing notification is this correct? If you do, could you show code where you register/unregister notification for? Having so many libraries and dependencies will be hard to see where problem lays, as you said. I think you are correct and some object is not unregistering observer properly, doesn't have to be in your code of course.

Comment: That's right, I never registered for that notification - never knew of it actually, since it's obviously a non-public one. I've made a search through all libraries' source code and it doesn't have this notification name either... So yeah, I'll just see how it goes on. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this issue and found a solution that did not involve removing notifications.  In our case, there was old code that was doing this:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
  // other stuff
}
```

I do not know why we had this, but it is gone now and the crash is gone.  It appears that in this case, resigning first responder while searchBarTextDidBeginEditing is being called orphans a notification on the search bar's text edit field, and then we'd crash as soon as the view controller owning this UISearchBar was deallocated and we did the background / foreground dance.

YMMV

Comment: Indeed, there's a couple of places in my app that do nearly the same thing! I've tried to reproduce the same scenario on iOS 6.0 Simulator - and turned out this was indeed the case! It's a pity that I don't work on this app anymore, but it's still worth knowing about this bug, so thank you! I'm sure to google around whether this bug was already documented and if not - I'll post a bug report.

Comment: I should also note here that instead of trying to resign first responder in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing, I must have implemented searchBarShouldBeginEditing and return NO in cases when search bar should've stayed put. It's not documented anywhere that I can't call resignFirstResponder in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing though, and the same trick works without any problems for a simple UITextField.

Comment: By the way, I can confirm that this issue has been fixed in the latest version of our favorite mobile OS that I probably can't mention because of NDA :)

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same stack trace in a crash report from a device running IOS 6.0.1. I managed to reproduce the problem on Simulator through the following pattern:

- Put the application in the background
- Simulate a memory warning from simulator menu
- Bring the application back to the foreground

After a lot of debugging I discovered that the *_applicationResuming:* message is sent to a *UITextField* which I am releasing as a reaction to Memory Warning. I tested the same pattern under IOS 5.1 but it didn't cause a crash. For some reason in IOS 6 UITextField registers for ApplicationResumeEvent (maybe not always but after the keyboard has appeared).
My workaround was to remove this object from NSNotificationCenter before releasing it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.placeFld];
self.placeFld = nil;
```

Comment: Wow, if I could just confirm this in my case, it would be a major "in your face" to everyone who still thinks it's my fault this happens in my app. I'm still having rare crashes reported because of this problem, so I'll try to reproduce it the way you described. I've already moved on to another project though, so it might take some time... Thank you anyway!

Comment: I had to go through a hard debugging session with breakpoints in assembly code in -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] and __CFNotificationCenterAddObserver_block_invoke_0. Then I could inspect the objects receiving the notification using their address from $ecx register. I went through such a session without simulating the memory warning taking a list of objects receiving the notification (po $ecx will give you the contents of a UITextField making the identification more easy). Then repeated the session with memory warning. The objects receive the notification in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

Put a breakpoint on `-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]`. It's trying to send a notification to an object that isn't there any more, or something like that. You may be mismanaging your own notifications or your own objects.

Consider switching to ARC if you are not using it already.

Use the static analyzer. It can find potential memory issues.

Comment: Thanks, I've used a breakpoint and a "wildcard" observer-callback to go through all generated notifications with stack trace logging, please see the results in an update for my question. And yes, I'm already using ARC and run static analyzer regularly. Might've been useful to mention that this app I'm working on is nearly a year old and I've already seen many kinds of crashes and fixed them...

Answer (score 1):

Could be many things, but I think checking in code who registers for ANY UIApplication notification would be better. You don't really know which notification triggers the error.

Also, is any object retaining/holding strong reference on the AppDelegate? It may cause some weird retain cycle making this crash happen.

I've never seen such a crash by XCode misbehaviour.

EDIT: Pasting all notifications from header file. may be overkill but some could be sent on app resume/from background

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification       NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification      NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification; // userInfo contains NSNumber with new orientation
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification;  // userInfo contains NSNumber with old orientation
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey;            // userInfo dictionary key for status bar orientation
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification;       // userInfo contains NSValue with new frame
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification;        // userInfo contains NSValue with old frame
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey;                  // userInfo dictionary key for status bar frame
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey                NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); // userInfo contains NSURL with launch URL
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); // userInfo contains NSString with launch app bundle ID
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); // userInfo contains NSDictionary with payload
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0); // userInfo contains a UILocalNotification
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey         NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2); // userInfo contains object with annotation property list
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable    NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey           NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0); // app was launched in response to a CoreLocation event.
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0); // userInfo contains an NSArray of NKAssetDownlo
```

Comment: Thanks, it's actually worth giving a try! I'm suspecting `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` by the way... Will investigate it soon.

Answer (score -1):

A few things I do to clear the deck before debugging something an odd crash.

Build Clean (gets rid of local cached files).

Delete the app from Simulator / Device (sometimes XIBs are cached).

Re launch Xcode (there are some weird bugs when Xcode isn't in sync with the current setup).

Then, try again.

Comment: Thanks, but this problem exists on both debug and release (both App Store and Ad-hoc) configurations, and I've done Clean a couple of times in between, so I guess that's not the cause.