# UILocalNotification crashes my application when I start it

Tags: iphone, ios6, crash, uilocalnotification

I can enable an `UILocalNotification` in my application, I proceed like this:

in my `UIViewController`

```
if(_endDate){    
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotif == nil)
            return;
        localNotif.fireDate = _endDate;
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        localNotif.alertBody = @"go";
        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }
```

in `Appdelegate`:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

When the notification appears, I launch the app, I enter into the delegate correctly but after that, the application crash.

I work in IO6

Can you help me ?

Comment: What is the crash message? Paste the log...

Comment: On which line, it crashes? What is the crash log?

Comment: There is no message, there are an infinity of breakpoints (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Comment: put return; after  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif]; or also check you have not release any variable that can you use in method after relase

Comment: Solution is in this topic: [iOS app crashes on resuming][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601406/ios-app-crashes-on-resuming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for fineding creash you can do this following step for profile project like:-

in Xcode-->Product-->choose profile.

wait till project runs in instruction Zombies. press on Profile you found your simulator as normal run. when your app Cresh you just select consol like:-

[image]

you found where is crash log with variable hope you got it

Comment: with zombie I have the message "[UITextField _applicationResuming:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x24a22d00"

Comment: ok my frnd now you just need to visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601406/ios-app-crashes-on-resuming  :)