# wrapped android-app crashes on resume "no current context"

Tags: android, ios, cordova, opengl-es, resume

i got a webapp build via flambe/haxe which is wrapped by phonegap build to get an *.ipa* and  *.apk*. For now the only remaining error is that the app looses its context if i switch between apps or pressing home-button resulting in the following error on android:

```
"W/Adreno200-EGL(31381): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSetBlobCacheFuncsQCOM:5575>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER"    
"E/libEGL(31381): eglSetBlobCacheFuncsANDROID resulted in an error: 0x300c"      
"E/SurfaceTexture(31381): [unnamed-31381-1] updateTexImage: invalid current EGLContext"    
"E/CanvasTexture(31381): unexpected error: updateTexImage return -38"
```

The last two lines keep repeating (even after several minutes) until i close the app manually which results in the following error-message:

```
"E/libEGL(21636): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)"
```

Full errorlog can be viewed here: http://goo.gl/UkxwfI (Dropbox)

One thing that keeps bugging me is the following message since all "related" problems got that feature turned ON, but i cant find anything to change that.
"D/webcoreglue(31381): netstack: Memory Cache feature is OFF"

Another thing is with: **D/CordovaActivity(31381): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null**
As of http://goo.gl/qZWc4F (github) there seems to be a problem on resuming in cordova. (just strg+f "cb-3064")

Took me the whole day to use google on terms like:
EGL_BAD_PARAMETER, qeglDrvAPI_eglSetBlobCacheFuncsQCOM, SurfaceTexture, CanvasTexture, updateTexImage, invalid current EGLContext, eglSetBlobCacheFuncsANDROID, error: 0x300c, OpenGL ES API

but without any good hints or helpful info.

additional information:

> - tested on Sony Xperia J (ST26i) and android 4.1.2
> - min android SDK 14
> - android:hardwareAccelerated="true" (default since sdk 14)
> - landscape + fullscreen
> - webview used to display the website coming from flambe/haxe
> - used build phonegap / phonegap 3.3 (using 2.8 - 3.3 = same)
> - building it myself via cordova doesnt help (so it should not relate to phonegap build)
> - cordova.inappbrowser only used to open links in external browser, website running in webview
> - website only shows a html5-game (nothing fancy, just something like bejeweld)

Maybe there's some easy help by juggling with the Android-Manifest. I really dont want to do native since the webapp is shipped to iOS via Phonegap too.

**Update 1**

Tried to reproduce the error using native android and playing with different manifest-settings. But it seems like this has something to do with how phonegap/cordova handles the drawing of everything on screen.

Next things to do will involve posting on phonegap-forums and checking out iOS errorlog. Maybe i find something while comparing my results to: [iOS app crashes on resuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601406/ios-app-crashes-on-resuming?rq=1)

**Update 2**

iOS-Errorlog doesn't help. Exception Type 20 and Exception Code 8badf00d. Stack shows errors with graphics too (like in android). Errorlog see Link in Comment...

Comment: same problem on iOS with phonegap build and/or manually using cordova (app freezes after resume and gets killed by the system a few seconds later -> app restarts)

Comment: http://goo.gl/YieKnY (Dropbox, Errorlog)

Comment: hi Killuah, do you know where I can find how to integrate Cordova view with OpenGL `GLSurfaceView`? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fixed" by building android and ios myself with cordova. Resuming/Restarting feels a bit bumpy but thats the next thing to fix.

Phonegap build just doesn't like the life cycle of apps.